# Line of Sight with Ray in XNA/Monogame

Tags: c#, xna, monogame, xna-4.0

I'm trying to create a Line of Sight method for an enemy class. However, it always returns false, no matter how close the player is to the enemy or whether the ray passes through any blocks to get to the player.

```
public virtual bool PlayerInLOS()
    {
        Vector3 middleOfPlayer = new Vector3(Level.Player.Position.X, Level.Player.Position.Y - Level.Player.BoundingRectangle.Height / 2, 0);
        Vector3 middleOfEnemy = new Vector3(Position.X, Position.Y - localBounds.Height / 2, 0);

        Vector3 direction = middleOfPlayer - middleOfEnemy;
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector3.Distance(middleOfEnemy, middleOfPlayer);

        if (direction != Vector3.Zero)
            direction.Normalize();

        Ray lineOfSight = new Ray(middleOfEnemy, direction);

        float? lineToPlayer = lineOfSight.Intersects(Level.Player.BoundingBox);

        foreach (BoundingBox box in Level.boundingBoxes)
        {
            float? distanceToIntersect = lineOfSight.Intersects(box);

            if (distanceToIntersect == null)
                continue;
            else if (distanceToIntersect < visionLength && distanceToIntersect < distanceToPlayer && distanceToIntersect != null)
                return false; 
        }

        // Never gets to this part because it always returns before it exits the for loop
        if (lineToPlayer < visionLength)
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What debugging have you done, maybe show with comments where you have debugged and what happened

Comment: I've done relatively little debugging since I've gone through it step by step in my head multiple times and I can't see where it could be messing up. I tried moving around the checks in the if statement in the foreach loop but it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing the problem by implementing an entirely different solution: checking every Vector2 along the distance between the enemy and the player. Works perfectly.

```
    public bool CanSeePlayer()
    {
        Vector2 middleOfPlayer = new Vector2(Level.Player.Position.X, Level.Player.Position.Y - Level.Player.BoundingRectangle.Height / 2);
        Vector2 middleOfEnemy = new Vector2(Position.X, Position.Y - localBounds.Height / 2);

        Vector2 direction = middleOfPlayer - middleOfEnemy;
        float distanceToPlayer = Vector2.Distance(middleOfEnemy, middleOfPlayer);

        if (visionLength > distanceToPlayer) // If the enemy can see farther than the player's distance,
        {
            if (direction != Vector2.Zero)
            direction.Normalize();

            for (int y = 0; y < Level.tiles.GetLength(1); ++y) // loop through every tile, 
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < Level.tiles.GetLength(0); ++x)
                {
                    if (Level.GetCollision(x, y) != TileCollision.Passable) // and if the block is solid,
                    {
                        Vector2 currentPos = middleOfEnemy;
                        float lengthOfLine = 0.0f;

                        Rectangle tileRect = new Rectangle(x * Tile.Width, y * Tile.Height, Tile.Width, Tile.Height);

                        while (lengthOfLine < distanceToPlayer + 1.0f) // check every point along the line
                        {
                            currentPos += direction;

                            if (tileRect.Contains(currentPos)) // to see if the tile contains it.
                            {
                                return false;
                            }

                            lengthOfLine = Vector2.Distance(middleOfEnemy, currentPos);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // If every tile does not contain a single point along the line from the enemy to the player,
            return true;
        }
        return false;            
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to check if enemy is within angle of sight, and in some distance you could try this code.

```
public static bool InLOS(float AngleDistance, float PositionDistance, Vector2 PositionA, Vector2 PositionB, float AngleB)
{
    float AngleBetween = (float)Math.Atan2((PositionA.Y - PositionB.Y), (PositionA.X - PositionB.X));
    if ((AngleBetween <= (AngleB + (AngleDistance / 2f / 100f))) && (AngleBetween >= (AngleB - (AngleDistance / 2f / 100f))) && (Vector2.Distance(PositionA, PositionB) <= PositionDistance)) return true;
    else return false;
}
```

credits: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/26813/xna-2d-line-of-sight-check